# Want to retrieve values not other details from array object in rally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rally

Want to retrieve below values from array object not other details, but getting whole data like events, listeners, etc.

`2014-10-01: 02014-10-02: 02014-10-06: 42014-10-08: 50.2857142857142852014-10-09: 42014-10-10: 32014-10-13: 32014-10-14: 2.52014-10-15: 52014-10-16: 02014-10-20: 32014-10-21: 12014-10-27: 32014-10-28: 6.7777777777777782014-10-29: 12014-10-31: 0.66666666666666662014-11-03: 42014-11-04: 19.252014-11-05: 33.62014-11-06: 12014-11-07: 32014-11-10: 32014-11-11: 3.6666666666666665`

[image]

Below is my some of the code which generate this object, any help on this please..

```
                var daysOfMonth = new Ext.util.HashMap();
                //console.log("startdate", this.startDate);
                //console.log("enddate", this.endDate);
                start = new Date(this.startDate);
                end = new Date(this.endDate);
                for (start; start <= end; start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)) {
                    daysOfMonth.add(new Date(start), null);
                }   
                //daysOfMonth = Ext.Array.flatten(daysOfMonth);
                console.log("days of month", daysOfMonth);

                var userstory_cycle_times_by_date = this._getCycleTimes(userstory_snaps_by_date);
                var storydaysOfMonth = Ext.Object.merge(daysOfMonth, userstory_cycle_times_by_date);

                //console.log("days of month", daysOfMonth);
                var defect_cycle_times_by_date = this._getCycleTimes(defect_snaps_by_date);
                var defectdaysOfMonth = Ext.Object.merge(daysOfMonth, defect_cycle_times_by_date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an object of all the key/value pairs like so:

```
_.reduce(daysOfMonth.getKeys(), function(result, key) { 
    result[key] = daysOfMonth.get(key); 
    return result; 
}, {});
```

I'm curious why you're using a HashMap to begin with rather than just a regular plain old javascript object literal?

Comment: thanks, yes there was no need to use HashMap, replaced that with primitive hash type..thanks for this